# regex to match first occruence and everything in between until last match

Tags: javascript, regex

I may be thinking this about the wrong way.

The first three `(...)`'s are generated and could be any number. I only want to catch these first set of items and allow the user to use `()` inside of their custom string.

## Test String

```
(374003) (C6-96738) (WR183186) R1|SALOON|DEFECTIVE|WiFiInfotainment|Hardware detects WIFI but unable to log in on the (JAMIE HUTBER) internet.:
```

## Regex

```
/\(([^)]+)\)/g
```

## Current output

```
 ["(374003)", "(C6-96738)", "(WR183186)", "(JAMIE HUTBER)"]
```

## Desired Output

```
 ["(374003)", "(C6-96738)", "(WR183186)"]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last item in the current output be `"(JAMIE HUTBER)"` and not just `"(JAMIE)"`?

Comment: Try `s.match(/\s*\(([^)]+)\)/gy)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/gAZNQw/1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two ways to do that:

1. get only 3 items from array
2. add space to your regexp `\(([^ )]+)\)` (https://regex101.com/r/ZPdq35/1/)

Comment: I have to admit... I need to understand this space idea :) Becuase right now I don't get why this works lol

Comment: @JamieHutber It works because there is a space in `JAMIE HUNTER`,

Comment: ... and here I was thinking that there was a magical new ` ` operator in regex that I hadn't the foggiest as to what it did... slamming my head on the table. lol

Answer (score 0):

Using the sticky option `/y` you can then use regEx's ability to find all occurrences..

This will then work, if there is not a space in `JAMIE HUNTER`, etc..

eg.

```js
const re = /\s*\(([^)]+)\)/y;
const str = "(374003) (C6-96738) (WR183186) R1|SALOON|DEFECTIVE|WiFiInfotainment|Hardware detects WIFI but unable to log in on the (JAMIE HUTBER) internet.:";

let m = re.exec(str);
while (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
  m = re.exec(str);
}
```